# How to increase badge count notification in the Android app icon using Ionic 2?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, notifications, ionic2

I developed an app for Android using Ionic 2.
The app works fine and the notifications are sended correctly to the app.
However, always I receive a push notification, the icon badge wich count the notifications does not appear.

I tried a lot, I searched a lot in the internet and none solutions works.

Informations:

1. I have the `cordova-plugin-badge` installed.
2. In my `app.component.ts` I already imported the Badge Plugin: `import { Badge } from 'ionic-native';`
3. To test, I setted the badge count to 10, with this code: `Badge.set(10);` - I putted this code inside `constructor` in `app.components.ts`.

I followed the [Ionic tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/badge/) to use the badge.

I tried to develop using the [plugin tutorial](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge), but it is not especific to Ionic. Then, I dont know how this can help.

I used the [Ionic 2 tutorial to do the push notifications](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/) and, how I said, works fine.

Well, the Ionic documentation about the Badge informes that I have to use the `Badge.increase(x)`. I don't know where to put this code. I thought I have to specify: When the notifications comes to the device, then `Badge.increase(x)`. But, I don't know how to do this.

My Push notification code is:

```
this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
  return this.push.saveToken(t);
}).then((t: PushToken) => {
  console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
});

this.push.rx.notification()
.subscribe((msg) => {
  alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
  Badge.clear();
});
```

But this code runs only with the app opened.
When I receive a background notification, how to increase the badge?

**Another important information:**

I emulate the Android using Android Emulator, provided by Android Studio.
The [device specs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzIAcHL8dij9QTVpUS1YZmcwYk0/view?usp=sharing).

In the Android Device Monitor, I see this error:

```
01-25 21:26:54.558: W/PackageManager(6769): Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ in package com.ionicframework.myapp343731
01-25 21:26:54.558: W/PackageManager(6769): Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE in package com.ionicframework.myapp343731
```

The error list [continues here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzIAcHL8dij9d0M1VmM1Q28xa2c/view?usp=sharing).

Try to search for this error in Google. There are few results.
Zero results specifics to Ionic. Awesome, huh?

And... I see badge count notifications in Android.
Is possible to do this. But, how?

Sorry my english and the long text.

Thanks!

**EDIT 1 --------------------**

My environment:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
node -v: v5.12.0
npm -v: 3.8.6
ionic -v: 2.2.1
cordova -v: 6.4.0
cordova-plugin-badge version: 0.7.4
```

**EDIT 2 --------------------**

My PHP code wich send the notification to Ionic via CURL:

```
$yourApiSecret = "myApiSecret"; // Available in Ionic Dashboard
$androidAppId = "myAndroidAppId"; // Available in Ionic Dashboard
$api_token = "my.api.token"; // Created in Ionic Dashboard

$data = array(
    "tokens" => "send_to_all",
    "profile" => "my_created_profile", //Created in Ionic Dashboard
    "send_to_all" => true,
    "notification" => array(
        'title'     => $title,
        'message'   => $message,
        )
    );

$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
    array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'X-Ionic-Application-Id: '.$androidAppId,
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$api_token
        )
    );

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: When sending a push notification from your back-end, you're able to give provide a badge count.

Comment: Hi @JoeriShoeby, thanks for the answer. But, how can I do this? I tried so much and nothign works. Using Ionic 2, how to put a badge count in the app icon while receive a push notification?

Comment: What do you have as back end server ?

Comment: @JoeriShoeby I integrated my Ionic App with Firebase. In my host, using PHP, I send a POST via CURL to Ionic's notifications URL. The Ionic connect to Firebase wich send the notifications. Below the tutorials that I followed: [Implementing Notification](http://docs.ionic.io/services/push/)  /  [Sending CURL to Ionic](https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications-guide/) - Only CURL part /  [Ionic's CURL params](http://docs.ionic.io/api/endpoints/push.html#post-notifications) - The push notifications works fine

Comment: Please provide your PHP code.

Comment: @JoeriShoeby I putted the code in **EDIT 2** in the answer. Thanks the attention!

Comment: Add a badge property to your 'notification' array

Comment: Thanks, but in the [Ionic 2 documentation](https://docs.ionic.io/api/endpoints/push.html#post-notifications), in the section **POST  /push/notifications** subsection **Request Body** there is no parameter **badge** for Android, it is only for iOS. Do you know how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

you need to send something like this to set badge to 5:

```
{ "data": {
"badge": "5"},"to" : "your push token"}
```

notice to make this work for android you should not send notification object with it. Only data. This way android app will wake up. On IOS you can get current badge and increment it using plugin. What I usually do it to calculate the badge on the backend and sent new badge

Comment: Hi @yernar-amergaliyev, thanks the answer. The problem is that Ionic has no "badge" param for Android. Look the [Ionic's CURL params](http://docs.ionic.io/api/endpoints/push.html#post-notifications). Using Ionic, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: yes android does not support badge. Every android phone producers does it themself. there is a plugin for that. just use it. And sent data notification for android phones. they will wake up the app and you can change the badge using your plugin

Comment: Where is the increment part? If the badge is already displaying a count lets say 1 and another notification has been received then how to you increase the count on badge to lets say 2 in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I just recently ran into the same problem. Android does not support badges on push notifications by default. But it can be done: To make this work, you need a combination of [ionic-native/badge](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/badge/) with push notifications.

Push notifications can be sent as a background notification by setting `content_available: 1` in the payload, reference: http://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#ios-background-notifications

Although the link mentions specifically iOS, you can get it to work on Android by using the following payload through Ionic Push notifications:

```
"notification": {
    "android": {
        "content_available": 1,
        "payload": {
            "badge": 5,
            "title": "Alert",
            "text": "Notifications"
        },
        "data": {
            "badge": 5
        }
    }
}
```

What this means:

`content_available:1` tells the device when receiving the push notification that it's a background notification that should not alert the user. So your app will be able to process the notification without bothering the user.

`payload` This is a preference, but here's why I have this: there's a magic combination, for me, with these background push notifications. I don't want the user alerted when the app is closed, but I want to handle it when the app is open. You can't put a `title` and `message` on a background push notification and still have it silently delivered in the background (at least on Android), so I put this information on the payload and then manually access it.

`data` This is the magic sauce that allows Android to process this background notification. Using the push plugin ionic provides, the payload structure is extremely pertinent to how the app processes the notification. Here's a good reference: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#notification-vs-data-payloads

Now, to handling the message in the app.

First, make sure you've properly followed the `ionic-native/push` documentation for setting up the plugin and injecting it into your app.

Define the provider in `app.module`

```
import { Badge } from '@ionic-native/badge';

providers: [
    Badge
]
```

Import all the things you'll need:

```
import { Push, PushToken, IPushMessage } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
import { Platform, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Badge } from '@ionic-native/badge';
```

Inject it:

```
constructor(
    private badge: Badge
) {}
```

Use it to handle a payload:

```
this.push.rx.notification()
    .subscribe((message: IPushMessage) => {
        console.log(message);
        if (message.title && message.text) {
            let notification: AppNotification = {
                title: message.title,
                message: message.text
            };
            // Handle the push notification in app.
        }

        let payload: any = message.payload;
        // Get the badge number off the payload.
        if(payload && payload.badge) {
            // Using the badge plugin, set the badge number.
            this.badge.set(Number(payload.badge));
        }

        if(payload && payload.title && payload.text) {
            let notification: AppNotification = {
                title: payload.title,
                message: payload.text
            };
            // Do something with the background notification if the app is open.
        }
    });
```

Following the ionic documentation for the `badge` plugin, when you receive a push notification, you can take the payload data and then use it to set the badge number. Additionally, if you would like you can also handle the push notification in the app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks the answer, I will try!